# I have a mistakes: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass and undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

Table `years` includes following fields: `id`, `name`.

Table `course` includes: `id`,

table `year_courses` includes: `year_id` and `course_id`.

I receive an exception:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass and undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Are you able to this in the console?

Comment: The first line should be `<%= content_tag_for :tr, @year_courses.each do |yc| %>`

Comment: Hmm, if you were using Rails standard conventions for a HABTM, your join table would be `courses_years`. It appears you're doing something weird, and I think may be a factor in your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because for some of your YearCourse (yc) objects, they do not have years, and some do not have courses so when rails tries to invoke `.name` on an already nil value `yc.year` you end up with a 'nilnil class' error. The other error you have is exactly the same except its for course.

To solve this in particular, you could try the following:

```
<%= content_tag_for :tr, @year_courses do |yc| %>

        <%= yc.year.try(:name) %></div>
        <%= yc.course.try(:id) %></div>

<% end %>
```

.try will "try" to invoke the method, and if it fails it will not raise an error. That being said, generally in rails coding, overuse of the method `try` can lead to a lot of bad coding practice. It can also indicate a code smell that would point to the fact that its possible the modelling could be done in a better way. Otherwise, you can always check if `yc.year.present?` and `yc.course.present?` before you try invoking `.name` and `.id` respectively.

Comment: Ideally, the try shouldn't be necessary. There's something wrong with the modeling if this is the solution.

Comment: I would agree with @MarkThomas in the fact that the modeling is not ideal in this case - but in terms of purely a solution to what OP is asking, this will work. I would however, review that data model closer and see if there are ways you can get around not having to code your views in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to solve the nil:NilClass error is to dump the data(that's if your app is using dummy data that you are experimenting with), reseed the data with all necessary attributes. `rake db:reset`. or `rake db:drop` and then `rake db:seed`